# Get addition of row values based on coresponding row values SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data base table(dbo.TestTable_1) like following:

```
Result    Value1    Value2

Y           A           1
            A           0
            B           1
            A           1
            B           0
```

I have to read top 1 of column "Value1" and check, in which row(of column Value1) matches the value. get the corresponding rows values and add it.If my addtion is > 0 then I want to return Yes, else return NO.

For example:

```
"select top 1 Value1 from dbo.TestTable_1" will return A.
```

Then I need to find the row number where A exists in "Value1". That is (here it is at), Row number 1,2 and 4. Then I want to add the corresponding values in "Value2" column. That is 1+0+1 = 2(this is greater then 0) then I want to return YES.

My output table should look like following:

```
Result    Value1    Value2

YES           A           1
              A           0
              B           1
              A           1
              B           0
```

I have tried following query to achieve this. But I'm unable to proceed further.

```
declare @val1 int
set @val1 = (select top 1 Value1 from dbo.TestTable_1)
create table #Temp
(
Val1 int
)
Insert into #Temp
select Value1 
from dbo.TestTable_1
select * from #Temp
```

I hope, my explanation is understood. Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you just need to sum value2.  You don't need a temp table either:

```
declare @val1 int
set @val1 = (select top 1 Value1 from dbo.TestTable_1)

select CASE WHEN SUM(Value2) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
from dbo.TestTable_1
WHERE value1 = @val1
```